# Percorrendo um arquivo e dividindo seu conteúdo em outros arquivos separados usando Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = rdpcap("lalalao2.pcap")


#time slice de t em segundos : 10 minutos

t = 600
somaMin = pkts[0].time + t


valores=[]
for p in pkts:

    if p<=somaMin:

        valores.append(p)

    else:


        primslice =valores

        f=open("time1.txt",'w')
        f.writelines(primslice)

        valores=[]

        valores.append(p)

        somaMin=p.time + t
```

O código acima abre um arquivo de dump de rede (PCAP) e cria vetores contendo time slices de t segundos. Gostaria que cada time slice fosse gravado em um arquivo texto diferente: time1, time2, ...
O problema é que não sei quantos slices terei, pois depende da captura. É possível?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, basta fazer com que o nome do arquivo seja variável. Algo como `open('time{}.txt'.format(i), 'w')` onde `i` é um contador.

```
from scapy.all import *

pkts = rdpcap("lalalao2.pcap")

i = 1
# ^--- Inicia o contador

#time slice de t em segundos : 10 minutos

t = 600
somaMin = pkts[0].time + t

valores=[]
for p in pkts:

    if p<=somaMin:

        valores.append(p)

    else:

        primslice =valores

        f=open("time{}.txt".format(i),'w')
        #           ^--- Deixa o nome do arquivo variável

        f.writelines(primslice)

        i += 1
        # ^--- Incrementa o valor de i indefinidamente enquanto necessário

        valores=[]

        valores.append(p)

        somaMin=p.time + t
```

Este código gerará os arquivos `time1.txt`, `time2.txt`, `time3.txt`, etc.

---

**Nota**: Na sua lógica, se o número de slices não for exatamente um múltiplo do tempo, você perderá o último slice (não será gravado em arquivo). Imagine que em cada slice serão gravados 100 registros, mas no final, no último slice, não sobrem os exatos 100, mas apenas 90. Quando fizer o loop, todos os registros entrarão no if `p<=somaMin`, mas nenhum entrará no `else`, onde é escrito o arquivo. Então recomendo que transforme a escrita em arquivo em uma função, chame-a dentro do else, se ainda desejar, mas depois do for, verifique se há elementos em `valores` e se sim, chame a função novamente.

Comment: sobre a nota é Só colocar o que sobrou fora do loop e gravar em outro arquivo

Comment: Que é exatamente o que eu falei, não é?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss, obrigado. Vou estudar o código aqui!